# Regrouping an Array with a Different key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data structure:

```
[
            {
                "_id": {
                    "question": "Voluptatem perferendis voluptas ex.",
                    "option": "Vero rerum qui animi quia assumenda."
                },
                "votes_by_gender": [
                    {
                        "user_gender": "F",
                        "total_votes": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "user_gender": "M",
                        "total_votes": 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "question": "Voluptatem perferendis voluptas ex.",
                    "option": "Suscipit iste molestias est est porro et atque."
                },
                "votes_by_gender": [
                    {
                        "user_gender": "M",
                        "total_votes": 2
                    }
                ]
            }, {...} , ...
]
```

I need to regroup it. I need a 'question' on the top of the route, and all other the same. So, I'm expeting something like:

```
[
 { _id : '$question', options : [{option, votes_by_gender},{...} ...] },
 ....
]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) before you [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$votes_by_gender" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.question",
    "options": {
      "$push": {
        "option": "$_id.option",
        "votes_by_gender": "$votes_by_gender"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which would output like:

```
{
        "_id" : "Voluptatem perferendis voluptas ex.",
        "options" : [
                {
                        "option" : "Vero rerum qui animi quia assumenda.",
                        "votes_by_gender" : {
                                "user_gender" : "F",
                                "total_votes" : 1
                        }
                },
                {
                        "option" : "Vero rerum qui animi quia assumenda.",
                        "votes_by_gender" : {
                                "user_gender" : "M",
                                "total_votes" : 2
                        }
                },
                {
                        "option" : "Suscipit iste molestias est est porro et atque.",
                        "votes_by_gender" : {
                                "user_gender" : "M",
                                "total_votes" : 2
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

Of course if you just mean bring the "question" only together without regrouping the array content, then you just [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.question",
    "options": {
      "$push": {
        "option": "$_id.option",
        "votes_by_gender": "$votes_by_gender"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which would output like:

```
{
        "_id" : "Voluptatem perferendis voluptas ex.",
        "options" : [
                {
                        "option" : "Vero rerum qui animi quia assumenda.",
                        "votes_by_gender" : [
                                {
                                        "user_gender" : "F",
                                        "total_votes" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "user_gender" : "M",
                                        "total_votes" : 2
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "option" : "Suscipit iste molestias est est porro et atque.",
                        "votes_by_gender" : [
                                {
                                        "user_gender" : "M",
                                        "total_votes" : 2
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

But that is arrays within arrays, and not really recommended even if you thought you wanted that.